# Using LIKE to match a string to a string containing multiple words

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-like

In mysql, I have a WHERE clause that uses LIKE to match a keyword to a string.

```
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
```

This almost works, but I running into a problem where titles with multiple words are returning erroneous matches.  For example, the keyword "press" would be matched to the title "depression sucks" - which should not happen.

What is the best way to ensure that the keyword matches only if it is at the start of a word?

Thanks (in advance) for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Word boundary markers `[[:<:]]`, `[[:>:]]`  are your friend.

```
mysql> SELECT 'a word a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';   -> 1
mysql> SELECT 'a xword a' REGEXP '[[:<:]]word[[:>:]]';  -> 0
```

Comment: Thanks - didn't know you could do that.  Works great!

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE title LIKE CAT(?, ' %')
```

the % is the wildcard character so if you have it in front and in back, it will look for anything that contains the ?. If you remove the first %, it will be anything that starts with the ?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  That isn't quite what I'm looking for.  I would like to match complete words.  So for example, if I have a title "The Quick Brown Fox" and the keyword "Brow" - using the above code would not work.

Comment: @Travis: Does putting a space between the search term & the wildcard suit your needs?

Comment: @OMG Ponies - almost.  But that would not work for the first word in the string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `MATCH` rather than `LIKE`. With proper indexing, `MATCH` is also much faster.

Here are the basics: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I am using innoDB - full text searching is not available

Comment: Whoops. Oh well, looks like codaddict has a good solution for you!

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with mysql, but I have used REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle... mysql seems to support something similar...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Then just write the appropriate regex.

Comment: REGEXP in MySQL ensures a table scan - can't use an index

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('% ', ?, '%') OR title LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')
```

This way, the query will find the keyword if it's the beginning of a word or the beginning of a title. So, if the keyword is 'cat', it will find the movies:

```
catwoman
dogs and cats
```

but not a movie like:

```
concatenation
```